# Update Case in Content Provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm migrating all my SQLite queries to a Content Provider in order to use SyncAdapter, but im facing a problem with an update-case which i dont know how to pass to the resolver. The query is this:

```
public void updateGroupSortAllPositions(List<Group> list)
{
    mngr.dbOpenRW();

    String query = "UPDATE " + DB_GROUP_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + DB_GROUP_COLUMN_SORT_POSITION + " = CASE " + DB_GROUP_COLUMN_ID + " ";

    for (Group g : list)
    {
        query += " WHEN " + g.getId() + " THEN " + g.getOrder() + " "; 
    }

    query += " END WHERE " + DB_GROUP_COLUMN_ID + " IN ( ";

    for (int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (i != list.size()-1)
            query += list.get(i).getId() + ", ";
        else
            query += list.get(i).getId();
    }

    query += " )";

    mngr.rawSQL(query);

    mngr.dbClose();
}
```

(mngr its a wrapper of SQLiteDataBase i made, but that's not the deal here.)

The thing is that i don't know how to pass that List to the resolver, and the only thing i can think of is to make "N" updates (resolver calls), one for each row, but i'll lose the performance of the update-case query, which is a huge difference processing a large dataset.

**Clarification edit**

Since ContentResolver's update is like:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) 
{

}
```

I can only specify 1 value (per column) in ContentValues to modify for 1..N rows in Selection, while in the update-case i have, i can specify the value of each row all in 1 query/update. I know i can perform N ContentResolver.update's, one for each different value/row, but i'm willing to know if there is a way to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some more clarification on what exactly you are trying to do would be handy. It seems to me that you could just use another in statement for the Group Ids.

Comment: i've added more clarification. By the way, with the other statment you mean a method in the ContentProvider for passing the List<Group> ? I though about that, but how is the user of the provider supposed to know that he has to use that method...

Comment: With your clarification I would go with what @tyczj mentioned in his answer below. Using [ContentProvider#applyBatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29) in conjunction with the [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html) is what was designed for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update using ContentResolver you simply just call

```
getContentResolver().update(uri,contentValues,where,selectionArgs);
```

use your where clause to say what rows you want to update

that will update one row at a time, which I understand you dont want.

Then if thats the case I would use `ContentProviderOperation` to do batch updates

for example:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
```

Add a new operation to the list

```
operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(uir).withSelection(where,selectArgs).withValues(values).build());
```

after you put all your operations in your arraylist then you apply the batch

```
getContentResolver().applyBatch(authority, operations);
```

Of course you also have to override `applyBatch` in your content provider to do everything

Comment: Eventhough is not the "1-query" solution as i was looking for, as all updates are done in the same transaction i finally used the ContentProviderOperation option. Thanks